# Angular 4 - Can't get data from a function in service

Tags: angular

I have a few components that need to use same reference data, but I don't quite know how to do it. I want to write just one http service which collects the data and one function which returns the data. And I want to use that function everywhere in my components by importing the service.

Here is what I tried.

example.service.ts:

```
// http get
getRefCountriesService(): Observable<any[]> {
   this.countries = this.http.get<any[]>(this.refCountryListUrl);
   return this.countries;
}

// function which returns the data
getCountries(): any {
this.getRefCountriesService()
  .subscribe(countries => {
    this.countries = countries['_embedded']['refCountries'];
    return this.countries;
  });
}
```

example.component.ts

```
//here is where I want to get the data to a variable
ngOnInit() {
   this.countries = this.exampleService.getCountries();
}
```

I must be missing something incredibly simple, please help.

Comment: What error message did you get in Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` value in callback of `subscribe` doesn't mean returning the value from the function.

Instead you can subscribe to `getRefCountriesService` directly in order to get what you want

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.exampleService
      .getRefCountriesService()
      .subscribe(countries => {
    this.countries = countries['_embedded']['refCountries'];
  });
}
```

And for your purpose as comment below, you can use `map` operator at your service's `getRefCountriesService` to make this function as a common function:

```
getRefCountriesService(): Observable<any[]> {
  //do not save here this.countires because it is Observable => just return it.
  return this.http.get<any[]>(this.refCountryListUrl).map(countries => countries['_embedded']['refCountries']);
}

// component
ngOnInit() {
  this.exampleService
      .getRefCountriesService()
      .subscribe(countries => {
        this.countries = countries;
      });
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. this is what i did, and it works yeah but i want to make it a function in a service so that i could use it everywhere. i don't want to write this in multiple components.

Comment: @newb1849 ok, since you have kept the result at `countries` of your service, you can call the `getCountries` first and retrieve data by `exampleService.contries` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are return `this.countries` here

```
getRefCountriesService(): Observable<any[]> {
   this.countries = this.http.get<any[]>(this.refCountryListUrl);
   return this.countries;
}
```

but you are not mapping the data so once the response from service will come you won't get it. Also when you write

```
   this.countries = this.http.get<any[]>(this.refCountryListUrl);
   return this.countries;
```

this is returning a promise not the countries so rather you write like this

```
getRefCountriesService(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.refCountryListUrl).map(res => {
        this.countries = res.json()
    });
}
```

Let me know if any issues

Answer (score 0):

You misuse this.countries variable.
If you use this.countries as a variable. please refer below :

example.service.ts:

```
// http get
getRefCountriesService(): Observable<any[]> {
   //do not save here this.countires because it is Observable => just return it.
   return this.http.get<any[]>(this.refCountryListUrl);
}

// function which returns the data
getCountries(): any {
this.getRefCountriesService()
  .subscribe(countries => {
    //when this http service success, this.countries can save data.
    this.countries = countries['_embedded']['refCountries'];

  });
}

example.component.ts

//here is where I want to get the data to a variable
ngOnInit() {
   //you can call the getCountries function here, then this.countries will have data when http service is complete in the getCountries() function.
  //you do NOT need to use this.countries here
   this.exampleService.getCountries();
}
```

Comment: `this.contries` both exist at OP's component and service, but they don't share each other.

Comment: @Pengyy yes you are right. I misunderstood since the var name is same. I though that he will call another getCounties value function later after init :)